# Absorption & emission spectrum

Tags: thermal-radiation, absorption

Thermal radiation is visible - infrared - part of ultraviolet.

I wanted to know and more importantly have reference materials related to

What formula decides absorption spectrum of a substance.

And what decides *direction* of emitted thermal radiation, for example gases in atmosphere radiate thermal radiation in all directions, up, down and rest.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dielectric function (and sometimes the magnetic permittivity for magnetic materials) determines the absorption-emission properties. The direction depends on the geometry and composition.

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are many, many factors that will determine the absorption spectrum of a substance. And note that the absorption spectrum is not just a characteristic of a substance, but is also determiend by its geometry, temperature, density, presence of magnetic fields etc., etc.

Comment: @Mauricio Since geometry and composition determines direction, would it be correct to assume then it's matter of probability? Is there a paper\article that would prove or at least explains this?

Comment: @ProfRob does that mean it has to be determined empirically?

Comment: No, it means you should focus your question on a particular physical problem rather than the whole of radiation, matter and all its interactions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question since there are multiple mechanisms involved. Usually, one needs to assume some range of wavelengths to discuss.

For atoms and molecules you have electronic (transitions between electron energy levels) and molecular transitions (vibrational modes). In solids you can have transitions between energy bands in semiconductors, or excite the motion of electrons (plasmons) in metals. But more generally your absorption is defined by some difference in energy levels, and the energy of emission is defined by difference in energy levels with the direction depending on the details, and coherence of the system.

So depending on the material you will have a different model.

In general, when discussing thermal radiation, you should look up black body spectrum, and you will find that emissivity and absorptivity are related with strong absorbers being strong blackbody emitters. But the emissivity will on the type of materials but can also depend on the surface of the material with a rough surface radiating thermal radiation differently than a smooth or polished surface.  In general the radiation will be perpendicular to the surface, but if the surface is textured or patterned in clever ways  you can change the direction somewhat.

Probably best to narrow you question down...

Comment: About narrowing the question, would it help if I narrowed it down to gases in atmosphere, perhaps even to GHGs in atmosphere?

Comment: The absorption spectrum of a blackbody  = 0 at all wavelengths. There is no such thing as a strong blackbody emitter; all blackbodies at the same temperature have an identical spectrum. The emissivity of a blackbody is independent of what it is made of. Thermal radiation $\neq$ blackbody radiation.

Comment: Real materials have emissivity and absorptivity that alters the blackbody spectrum, or emission spectrum if you no longer want to call it a blackbody spectrum.

Comment: If you are interested in the atmosphere google atmospheric absorption and Stephan Boltzmann equation. Also with respect to heat transfer in the atmosphere it is complicated especially if clouds are involved.  https://www.weather.gov/jetstream/absorb  has a nice graph showing the sun's spectrum and the atmospheric window.